# HTML mailto fails to set custom mailing list as receiver

Tags: html, sharepoint, utf-8

The `mailto` link leaves an empty receiver when trying to adress a custom group.

```
<a href="mailto:#group-support@company.com">#group-support</a>
```

The customized groups start with `#`, do I have to escape this char in any way? Removing the `#` would work, but that isn't going to land in the correct mailbox. The problem occured in a SharePoint site, eventhough it seems to be a html propblem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparantly `%23` for `#` will do the trick in utf-8.